# Can't downloading HTML in Android Studio

Tags: java, html, android-studio

When I'm trying to download html using this method:

```
    public class DownloadHtml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int data = reader.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char currentChar = (char) data;
                result += currentChar;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

And logging a result

```
        DownloadHtml downloadHtml = new DownloadHtml();
    String result = null;
    try {
        result = downloadHtml.execute("http://stackoverflow.com").get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Html", result);
```

I am gettin only small part of it.
Is there a way to get whole HTML of webpage?

Comment: Your code should work (inefficiently).  Remember that many pages have lots of content which is generated dynamically with javascript, which your code won't be able to handle.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed It's quite slow, ultimately I have a webpage with names and images and I have to get link to images and get names. So in order to do that, I was thinking to get whole html and with Pattern get links and names respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple. Looks like Log.i doesn't print everything in one go.
When I have tried to get all the links from HTML they were successfully printed.